# Error in projection or just a graphical error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wgs84, utm

I've got a worldwide SRTM grid in WGS84 and want to reproject it to UTM coordinates.

If I do so in parts of the world are strange tiles of the map (especially in Eurasia), which are not part of the UTM stripe. You see a example in the map below for the UTM 5N in a Mercator projected map.
What are reasons for that?[image: UTM 5N with strange map parts in Eurasia]
As resamping technique I used bilinear.

Comment: What does it look like in UTM? Is the problem occurring when converting from WGS84 to UTM or from UTM to Mercator?

Comment: The problem occurs, when I convert a WGS 84 Layer to UTM and want to show it in a mercator projected map.

Comment: Again, what does it look like in a utm map? What happens if you reproject it to **mercator** instead??

Comment: In the UTM Map it looks normal, because the relevant areas are not in the map. When I reproject it to mercator those parts disappear.